# Using switch case

Tags: c++

This is what I have so far.  It won't work. I'm trying to write it to get user input of an amount and the county they live in and the program outputs the total with taxes

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    char amt = 0;
    double county ;
    char x = 0;
    double total = 0;
    total = amt + x;
    x = county;


    printf("\nplease enter amount\n");

    scanf_s("%d",&amt);

    printf("\nplease enter county\n");

    scanf_s("%c",&x);



    scanf_s("%c",&total );
    printf("total:", amt * x);
    switch(x)
        {
        case 'o':
            printf("orange:",county = 0.06);


            break;
        case 'l':
            printf("lake:",county = 0.07);


            break;
        case 's':
            printf("seminole:",county = 0.08);


            break;
        }






        system("pause");
}
```

Comment: And what seems to be the problem?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "won't work"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do you use switch case with math](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294186/how-do-you-use-switch-case-with-math)

Comment: What place do you live in that has floating point counties?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `printf()`, also specify which variables you are sending, so if you want to print a value use something like: `printf("Value: %f\n", 0.07);`. 
You can find the format specifiers [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/).

Answer (score 1):

You should put the `switch` clause before the line where you print the total. Also, from what I'm seeing you shouldn't multiply the `amt * x` but something like `subtotal * (1 + county)`

Answer (score 1):

If scanf_s() is anything like scanf(), you should consider using the right conversions for the arguments ("%d" means 'int' and so on).